# i want create bottomtab navigation after all adding the code it will shows error like this

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can anyone please help to overcome this problem?

Recently I am working in the react-native project, I want to create bottom tab navigation after all adding the code it will show error like this error below:

[image]

App.js Code:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({TabScreen});
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({Signin: LoginPage});

const App = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Starter: AuthLoadingPage,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Starter',
    },
  ),
);
```

[image]

Intab screen only I have created bottom tab navigation see this code:

```js
export const TabScreen = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-settings" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },
    Settings1: {
      screen: SettingScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
        tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Ionicons name="ios-settings" color={tintColor} size={25} />
        ),
      },
    },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red',
      inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
      showIcon: true,
    },
  },
);
```

Comment: I think you forgot to show the error you are getting.

Comment: I added the error image.. kindly check and correct me

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import {createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createAppContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
```

to

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you post your code where you are using createAppContainer

Comment: npm i react-navigation-stack --save have you tried it

Comment: I Used createAppContainer in App.js

Comment: I had some changes in my answer try using this latest imports

Comment: What were the changes you did...Kindly let me know. please

Comment: Use this imports.
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

Comment: try to del @react-navigation/native from your package.json and do npm install

Comment: import {TabScreen} from './src/Container/TabScreen'; what is the need of {} around TabScreen and you were saying that you are creating a buttomtabnavigator right, where you are importing it.

Comment: I have done these possibilities still replicating the same.